# Site sharing settings via CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Can these settings be accesed via CSOM?

[image]

Comment: out of these settings, exactly which setting you want to change using CSOM? Check [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/changing-the-quot-allow-members-to-share-quot-sharepoint-site/m-p/18951) & [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/10/sharepoint-online-access-request-email-settings-powershell.html) and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Just want to read them. Not change them.

Comment: Are access request settings and those settings the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a context object using your admin url. Then

```
using (context)
  {
   var tenant = new Tenant(context);
   SiteProperties siteProp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl("Site collection Url", true);
   context.Load(siteProp);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
 }

//site prop return various members of type enums which
define the sharing capability and sharing settings of the site

Edit:
For tenant level settings we can access them using
tenant.<<MemberName>>
```

Comment: I will test. Thanks.

Comment: Those settings are the sharing capabilities from SharePoint Admin? And not on the site? Like allow Guests ... ?

Comment: The site properties are specific to SharePoint site collections. Is it not what you are looking for? Please let me know.